# How to send email array list data in tabled manner via java?

Tags: jakarta-mail

How to send email array list data in tabled manner via java? I have two array list need to be mailed in two coloumn. Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Send a text/html message with the table formatted as an html table.

If that doesn't seem like the obvious answer, you'll need to explain a lot more about your requirements.